# Starting mysql in new EC2 instance throws "can't connect through socket" error

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I have an ec2 instance, but when i run mysql, it gives me this error

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Similarly, when i run

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start

Oct 31 11:29:16 domU-12-31-38-00-A8-62 /etc/init.d/mysql[5263]: error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, maybe the server is not running? :)

At the bare minimum:

```
ps aux|grep [m]ysql
```

If this returns nothing, then MySQL is not running.

Troubleshoot by adding the following to the config file: `log_error=/path/to/logfile`

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem on an ec2 instance. These [instructions](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-install-mysql-under-rhel/) worked perfectly for me:

---

**Redhat Enterprise Linux - RHEL 5 / 6 MySQL installation**

Type the following command as root user:

```
yum install mysql-server mysql
```

**Redhat Enterprise Linux - RHEL 4/3 MySQL installation**

Type the following command as root user:

```
up2date mysql-server mysql
```

**Start MySQL Service**

To start the mysql server type the following command:

```
chkconfig mysqld on
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

**Setup the mysql root password**

Type the following command to setup a password for root user:

```
mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD
```

**Test the mysql connectivity**

Type the following command to connect to MySQL server:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```