# Mysql can't connect to local server through socket on Amazon EC2

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I opened my application (in Rails) on Amazon EC2 and got an error - thus I checked the logs and there is following:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
```

10 hours ago was everything working yet. What's the problem? A lot of traffic?
The app is running on Micro Instance.

How to fix this issue and how to avoid it in the future?

Thank you very much

**EDIT:**

```
sudo find / -type s
---
/tmp/.sock
/dev/log
/var/lib/apt-xapian-index/update-socket
/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
/run/acpid.socket
/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
/run/udev/control
find: `/proc/4739/task/4739/fd/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/4739/task/4739/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/4739/fd/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/4739/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Sounds Similar like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq)

Comment: have you tried to `locate` your `mysqld.sock` file...using locate `mysqld.sock` command. Does the path matches with the `socket=path` in your `myconf` file??

Comment: Hello guys, thank you for your answers. `locate mysqld.sock` returns empty output, when I ran `sudo find / -type s`, I see there `/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` - how to deal with that?

Answer (score 8):

In my case, the server had apparently restarted at some point, and mysql was not started when it did.  I simply typed the command to start and it worked:

```
sudo service mysqld start
```

Comment: Or `sudo systemctl start mysqld.service`, depending on the OP's system. In which case it can be automated for future reboots, using `sudo systemctl enable mysqld.service`.

Answer (score 0):

locate your `locate my.cnf` file see there for line as `socket = ../../mysql.sock`
you need to replace the path with your path as

> socket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

if the path matches let me know

Comment: Thank you for your answer Amit. The output of `locate my.cnf` is `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, how to update it now?

Comment: `sudo vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf` and look for `socket=../../mysql.sock` line and see if the path for socket is same as `/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` otherwise replace it and save the file by pressing `Esc` + `:`+ `wq`

Comment: I did this update - the previous path was `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`, so I changed it. However, still the same issue. I tried also to restart `nginx`, but it didn't help me. But - in log is still the old path - `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111) (Mysql2::Error)`

Comment: try `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`

Answer (score 0):

Cross posting my response from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064541/starting-mysql-in-new-ec2-instance-throws-cant-connect-through-socket-error).

I had this same problem on an ec2 instance. These [instructions](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-install-mysql-under-rhel/) worked perfectly for me:

---

**Redhat Enterprise Linux - RHEL 5 / 6 MySQL installation**

Type the following command as root user:

```
yum install mysql-server mysql
```

**Redhat Enterprise Linux - RHEL 4/3 MySQL installation**

Type the following command as root user:

```
up2date mysql-server mysql
```

**Start MySQL Service**

To start the mysql server type the following command:

```
chkconfig mysqld on
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

**Setup the mysql root password**

Type the following command to setup a password for root user:

```
mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD
```

**Test the mysql connectivity**

Type the following command to connect to MySQL server:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used command below:

```
project_folder > mysql.server start
```

After system return SUCCESS message it worked OK.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql-server` is not installed by default on the Amazon Linux AMI. Use these commands to install it:

```
$ sudo yum install mysql-server
$ sudo chkconfig mysqld on
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld start
$ mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD
$ mysql -u root -p
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this error first find your socket file, run the following commands in terminal

```
mysqladmin variables | grep socket
```

For me, this gives:

```
| socket              | /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Then, add a line to your Rails application: config/database.yml:

```
development:
adapter: mysql2
host: localhost
username: root
password: xxxx
database: xxxx
socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

This will solve this problem.